# Stripe checkout session with auto tax calculation doesn't show Google Pay or Apple Pay when billing address collection is auto

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

When creating a Node js Stripe checkout session using automatic tax calculation, Google Pay and Apple Pay options aren't available when setting `billing_address_collection: 'auto'`. However, those wallet options are available if I set:

```
 shipping_address_collection: {
     allowed_countries: ['US'],
 },
```

Here is my entire create checkout configuration:

```
{
     mode: 'subscription',
     line_items: [
         {
              price: 'price_key',
              quantity: 1,
          },
      ],
      billing_address_collection: 'auto', // does not work
      // shipping_address_collection: { // works
      //     allowed_countries: ['US'],
      // },
      automatic_tax: {
          enabled: true,
      },
      allow_promotion_codes: true,
      success_url: `success_url`,
      cancel_url: 'cancel_url',
      customer: 'stripe_customer_id';
      customer_update: {
          address: 'auto', // does not work
          // shipping: 'auto', // works
       };
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to docs](https://stripe.com/docs/tax/checkout#:%7E:text=When%20you%20enable%20Stripe%20Tax,supports%20Apple%20Pay%20version%2012), when you enable Stripe Tax in Checkout, Apple and Google Pay are only available to customers for sessions that require collecting a shipping address. Therefore, this is expected.

Comment: I did see this as well - I'm going to see if I can raise it as an issue on a Stripe forum or GitHub since that doesn't really make sense imo